# Trying to change images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

This is my "button" that i want to change the icon to "open" and the to "close" when it's clicked again

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{pesquisa}" style="float:left; padding-top:2px;">
            <h:outputLink id="linkToggleControl" value="#">
                <rich:toggleControl event="click" targetPanel="painelFiltro" targetItem="#{filtroBean.activeItem eq 'ativo'? 'vazio' : 'ativo'}" />
                <h:graphicImage id="imagem-pesquisa" value="/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png" style="border:none; cursor:pointer;"/>
                <rich:tooltip layout="block" direction="auto">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.acsPesquisar}" />
                </rich:tooltip>
            </h:outputLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">             
            jQuery(function($) {                        
                $('.linkToggleControl').on({
                    'click': function() {
                        var src = ($('#imagem-pesquisa').attr('value') === '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png')
                            ? '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandir.png'
                            : '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png';
                         $('#imagem-pesquisa').attr('value', src);
                    }});         
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this sort of thing several times in Jquery, so I know it is possible. 
I have had a look at your script, and there are a few things that I would do differently. However, I am not accustomed to the code you are using. So my suggestion is how I would do it to work on HTML4, xHTML, HTML5.

Here is the way that I would do it:

```
$(function(){                      
    $('body').on('click','.linkToggleControl', function() {
        var src = ($('#imagem-pesquisa').attr('value') == '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png')? '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandir.png': '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png';
        $('#imagem-pesquisa').attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

Where I have used `'body'`, I would actually have used the parent of the `.linkToggleControl`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're calling the 'linkToggleControl' element, while this is his id or class, right? you should be using the '#' or '.' chars before the name to call them

so try it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

$('.linkToggleControl').on({
                'click': function() {
                     var src = ($('#imagem-pesquisa').attr('value') === '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png')
                        ? '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandir.png'
                        : '/resources/images/interface/pesquisa-barra-expandida.png';
                     $(this).attr('value', value);
                }
            });         
    </script>
```

checkout the 'linkToggleControl' to see his id or class, but the 'imagem-pesquisa' it's definitly missing the '#' char before it

Comment: it's my first time using jquery and it's not my code hehe,so i thought i just needed to use the id like that, and thanks for the help but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

You are using: 
  `$(this).attr('value', value);`

Should this not be :  `$(this).attr('value', src);`

Comment: not rly, but i couldn't do it due to a render so i did it without jquery

Comment: @JohnnySantana I had a closer look at your script and changed a few things. Please see my answer.